# Converting an Access database from 03 to 07 programatically with vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, format-conversion

I need to convert old .mdb Access files to the new .accdb format.
What's the best way to do this in vb.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Office `InterOp` to instantiate `Application` of Access and try to open .mdb, file then save it using [SysCmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214117%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method.

Honestly, I didn't tried so far yet but here are some undocumented sysCmd [code](http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Undocumented-SysCmd-Functions) but there  is a simple approach to convert .mdb to .acccdb via `ConvertAccessProject` method.

```
app = new  Application()

src ="c:\csnet\file.mdb"
dst= "c:\csnet\file.accdb"

app.ConvertAccessProject(src, dst, AcFileFormat.acFileFormatAccess2007)
app.Quit()
```

Comment: @JohnSaunders I've post a demo.